# Boot freezes at "Loading Initial ramdisk" (urgent)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, initramfs

I am trying to compile linux-3.13.11 on QEMU running linux-4.4.0 and followed the following steps to compile and load the kernel.
Everything is going fine, except during `update-mkinitramfs` command which throws

`blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0`

After all these steps, when I try to reboot and load into the new compiled Kernel, it freezes at

`loading initial ramdisk`

Any idea what might be wrong and how can I avoid this issue?

```
make i386_defconfig
make 
make modules 
make modules_install 
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to boot in the last good working kernel and delete the newest kernel via synaptic. after that, try to reinstall the kernel via the update manager.

regards.

Comment: Thanks Yirnik. I am able to resolve this issue by using the existing config of my working kernel and that seemed to be working.